# Background image of an element with dynamic width

Tags: html, css

[image: my navigation bar]

I'm in the process in coding a web design and i've spent the grandeur of my time thinking how will i be coding this navigation bar, where the `<li>` have dynamic widths where the background image adjusts to the width of the element.

My idea was to use `<span>` and slice the background image into three parts.

```
<li>
<span class="libefore"></span>
<a href="#">MOVIES</a>
<span class="liafter"></span>
</li>
```

What's the best way of coding this?

Answer (score 1):

Normally this is achieved with a technique called 'sliding doors' have a read over this:

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to go with CSS 2.1 :before and :after selectors (See here for supported browsers: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html), you could try something like this:

HTML:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Movies</a>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
li:before {
    background-color: #F00;
    content: '\00A0\00A0';
}

li a {
    background-color: #0F0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

li:after {
    background-color: #00F;
    content: '\00A0\00A0';
}
```

This keeps your HTML clean without introducing any presentational elements. (ie. No span elements that have no content or hierarchical purpose) Also, it's not a bad practice to use text-transform to take care of any uppercase transformations, just in case you want to change the style one day without having to modify the content.

Here is a fiddle which should give a bit of a starting point to tweak from: http://jsfiddle.net/6Keaa/

Hope this sets you in the right direction...